# regex matching image tag to retrieve URL

Tags: php, regex

I wrote `src="([^"]+)"`
and it does the following matches :
`<img src="http://google.com/q.jpeg">` matched

`<img alt="something" src="http://google.com/q.jpeg">` matched

`<audio src="http://something..">` matched too

How can I exclude video and audio?

Comment: What is the expected output....your regex should work frn for both cases

Comment: it matches the `src` strings in both.

Comment: You're capturing the URL only, what language do you use?

Comment: Could you explain this `And also video used src, I want only the URL of the img.` ?

Comment: Which language are you running?

Comment: @james lebron ... check my result it will work.

Comment: @Yash it's not the right behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
$sourcestring = '<img alt="something" src="http://google.com/q.jpeg">';
preg_match_all('/<img.*?src="(.*?)"/',$sourcestring,$matches);

print_r($matches[1])
```

is your output. It only accept  tag src values.

this will helpful for you.

Comment: We still don't know what language OP uses.

Comment: what if <video src="something.."> I do not want to include video or audio

Comment: I edited the code check this. It only accept <img /> src values.

Answer (score 1):

```
<img [^>]*src="([^"]+)"
```

Try this.Grab the capture or group.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/gX5qF3/9

Answer (score 1):

A simple regex would be:

```
<img\b[^>]*?\bsrc\s*=\s*(['"])(.*?)\1
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bQ9zY7/3)

But remember, [don't try this at home](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3764814) when better tools are available ;)